# How to minimize the execution time?

Tags: javascript, execution-time

I'm checking if the given string is palindrom or not, but the execution time is too long.

My code is below:

```js
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
  for (let i = 0; i < (inputString.length - 1) / 2; i++) {
    const a = inputString[i];
    const b = inputString.split("").reverse().join("")[i];
    if (a !== b) {
      return false;
    }
    continue;
  }
  return true;
}
const palindrome = checkPalindrome("abba");
console.log(palindrome);
```

How can I optimize the code in order to reduce it's execution time?

Comment: What about `inputString => inputString.split("").reverse().join("") === inputString` ?

Comment: In this case the value of inputString will be rewrited for const a as well, won't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are iterating each letter, When you can reverse it using array methods?

```js
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
  return inputString === inputString.split("").reverse().join("");
}

let palindrome = checkPalindrome("abba");
console.log(palindrome);

palindrome = checkPalindrome("random");
console.log(palindrome);

palindrome = checkPalindrome("abba isi abba");
console.log(palindrome);
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is the best. I don't know why I've decided to use cycle for here, as everything is much easire #facepalm )))

Comment: @Alice378 It happens. You can close the question accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can check with a simple `for` loop

```js
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
    const len = inputString.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        if (inputString[i] !== inputString[len - 1 - i])
            return 'not a palindrome';
    }
    return 'palindrome';
}

console.log(checkPalindrome('madam'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont repeat yourself! You're splitting and reversing the string every iteration.

```js
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
  const reversed = inputString.split("").reverse()
  for (let i = 0; i < (inputString.length - 1) / 2; i++) {
    const a = inputString[i];
    const b = reversed[i]
    if (a !== b) {
      return false;
    }
    continue; /// pointless also - you're already at the end of the loop
  }
  return true;
}


console.log(checkPalindrome("sir"))
console.log(checkPalindrome("madam"))
```

That's the big one, there are other micro optimizations you can make such as not evaluating the loop control every time, but it will make very little difference unless your input is huge.

Comment: So why not inputString.reverse() === inputString() ?

Comment: @HaiAlaluf no reason, except the OP didnt ask for "the simplest 1 line to check for a palindrome", they asked how to optimize their _existing code_.

Comment: It is more efficient as well

Comment: @HaiAlaluf Undoubtably!

Answer (score 0):

Even better:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var re = /[\W_]/g;
  // convert to lower case and remove spaces
  var lower = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
  // reverse the string
  var reverse = lower.split('').reverse().join(''); 
  // check if reversed and actual string is same
  return reverse === lower;
}

console.log(palindrome("sir"))
console.log(palindrome("madam"))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a little efficient `recursive` solution

```js
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
    const n = inputString.length
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
        return true;
    else{
        if(inputString[0] != inputString[n-1]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    const t = inputString.slice(1, n-1)
    return checkPalindrome(t)
    }

console.log(checkPalindrome("abbca"))
```

or either more efficient

```
    function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
        return (inputString.split("").reverse()).join('') === inputString
    }

console.log(checkPalindrome("abba"))
```